# Displaying Images in a folder in the Gallery App

Tags: android

I am looking to display photos from a specific folder on the sdcard in the gallery app.  Currently this code seems to display images from I'm not sure where:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media")));
```

in a way that is exactly how I want it to be in my app.  How can I get it so that it will display images from only this folder: 'sdcard/Pictures/Memorial'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

and then in `onActivityResult`, you can get the Uri's of the images from intent argument in `onActivityResult` method and show them wherever you like.

If you don't know how to parse image from Gallery,Uri, Google it.
There are many solutions

Answer (score 0):

### Sample code to pick image from a folder

```
public class SDCARD123Activity extends Activity implements MediaScannerConnectionClient{
    public String[] allFiles;
private String SCAN_PATH ;
private static final String FILE_TYPE="image/*";

private MediaScannerConnection conn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File folder = new File("/sdcard/Photo/");
    allFiles = folder.list();
 //   uriAllFiles= new Uri[allFiles.length];          
    for(int i=0;i<allFiles.length;i++)
    {
        Log.d("all file path"+i, allFiles[i]+allFiles.length);
    }
  //  Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/yourfoldername/"+allFiles[0]));


    SCAN_PATH=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Photo/"+allFiles[0];
    System.out.println(" SCAN_PATH  " +SCAN_PATH);

    Log.d("SCAN PATH", "Scan Path " + SCAN_PATH);
    Button scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startScan();
    }});
    }
    private void startScan()
    {
    Log.d("Connected","success"+conn);
    if(conn!=null)
    {
    conn.disconnect();
    }
    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this,this);
    conn.connect();
    }
@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    Log.d("onMediaScannerConnected","success"+conn);
    conn.scanFile(SCAN_PATH, FILE_TYPE);    
}
@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    try {
        Log.d("onScanCompleted",uri + "success"+conn);
        System.out.println("URI " + uri);             
        if (uri != null) 
        {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        } finally 
        {
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        }
       }
}
```